# Reading BinaryWebSocketFrame data PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, netty, openfl

I have a netty java server handling websockets.

I managed to handle handshakes and receive data from the HTML5 client. The problem I have is, the server receives `BinaryWebSocketFrame` and its data contains `PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 6, cap: 6)`.

How can I decode this data and see what it contains?

PS: My client is an OpenFL client that uses `openfl.net.socket`.

Answer (score 0):

A `ByteBuf` is just raw "bytes" so you will need to parse these. How you do this highly depends on what input your parser expect. Like for example you can read the data into a `byte[]` which you then pass over to your parser. Or you can use a `ByteBufInputStream` and use this if your parser supports `InputStream`.